# I have an error when reading a method with web3 (call)

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to learn how to integrate with web3 but I am having some problems. (normal I just started)

But there is a problem that I can't solve.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'retrieve' of undefined

I try to call a function but it does not work and I do not know how to solve it.

Here is the code:

```
const abi_c = [{"inputs": [],"name": "retrieve","outputs": [{"internalType": "uint256","name": "","type": "uint256"}],"stateMutability": "view","type": "function"},{"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint256","name": "num","type": "uint256"}],"name": "store","outputs": [],"stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "function"}];
const account = "0x644f1439DBfc743853031d79021890af54bCA8Ae";

const web3js = new Web3(window.ethereum);
ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;

var contract = web3js.eth.contract(abi_c, account);
var result = contract.methods.retrieve().call();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `web3js.eth.Contract` class with the `new` keyword.

```
var contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(abi_c, account);
```

Without it, the `var contract` is pointing only to the uninstantiated definitions and static properties.

Also, mind the capital `C` in `Contract` ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html)).

---

Then you're going to run into another issue.

The `.call()` method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you need to resolve it using the `await` expression (in an `async` function) or the callback function.

```
// needs to be in an async function
async function getResult() {
    var result = await contract.methods.retrieve().call();
    console.log(result);
}
```

```
contract.methods.retrieve().call().then(function (result) {
    // callback function
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still can't use a function that is not recognized by the program.

Comment: @TheStudent What do you mean by "not recognized by the program"? Does the script throw the same error message or a different one (in that case what is the message)?

Comment: the script return main.js:175 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'retrieve' of undefined
    at main.js:175

Comment: @TheStudent It seems like you didn't properly instantiate the `var contract`. Can you check that you're using the uppercase `C` and the `new` keyword as the asnswer defines? If you're using this correctly, also check that the address and ABI JSON (passed into the `new Contract` constructor) are valid.

Comment: thank you for your help.
I applied your directions but the problem remained so I searched and applied tutorials.
Then I found a tutorial that works using `window.nameofcontract`
I don't know why it works but using `window` in front of it, works.